# Python Pandas: conditional subtraction

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

[image]

I want to perform conditional subtraction on the dataframe (shown as the first picture).

Basically, this is what I want to do:

1. Subtract the values of col1 and col2 of food and clothing between me and you and create new rows for the differences.

Since the first row has 'food' and 'me' and the third row has 'food' and 'you', you subtract the values of col1 and col2 of the third row from the first row
(300 - 600 = -300, and 200 - 500 = -300).

Since the second row has 'clothing' and 'me' and the fourth row has 'clothing' and 'you', you subtract the values of col1 and col2 of the fourth row from the second row (500 - 200 = 300 and 600 - 700 = -100).

How do I implement this using Pandas dataframe?

Comment: `transport` dataframe pandas , like `df.T` and append column then transport it back

Comment: Please consider up-voting @ScottBoston's answer in addition to accepting it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it this way using `pd.concat`, `groupby` and taking advantage of Pandas intrinsic alignment of data based on indexes:

Input df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type1':['food','clothing','food','clothing'],'type2':['me','me','you','you'],'col1':[300,500,600,200],'col2':[200,600,500,700]})


pd.concat([df.set_index(['type1','type2'])
  .groupby('type1')
  .apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0]-x.iloc[1])
  .assign(type2='us')
  .set_index('type2', append=True),
  df.set_index(['type1','type2'])]).reset_index()
```

For Pandas older that 0.20.0

```
pd.concat([df.set_index(['type1','type2'])
  .groupby(level=0)
  .apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0]-x.iloc[1])
  .assign(type2='us')
  .set_index('type2', append=True),
  df.set_index(['type1','type2'])]).sort_index(level=[1,0]).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
      type1 type2  col1  col2
0  clothing    us   300  -100
1      food    us  -300  -300
2      food    me   300   200
3  clothing    me   500   600
4      food   you   600   500
5  clothing   you   200   700
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the code you wrote, but it gives me the KeyError: 'type1'
 mssage.

Comment: hrm... I just cut and pasted that exact code and it ran fine.

Comment: that's strange... hmm.. why do I get KeyError: 'type1' error lol

Comment: Are you running both statements?

Comment: Yes, I am. I think I get the error message when I get to the ".groupby('type1')" part.

Comment: Oh... yes... in the  pandas 0.20.3 you can reference index by name.  Change that out for groupby(level=0)... You are on a older version of pandas

Comment: lol, now it works! didn't know that I was using the older version. Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you think there's a way to achieve this using pd.pivot_table as well??

Comment: Yes, but I don't think pivot_table is going to yeild you the proper structure.  You have to reshape to get the output back like this.

Answer (score 2):

A way to do it with [**`eval`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.eval.html)

```
df \
  .set_index(['type2', 'type1']).unstack().T \
  .eval('us = me - you', inplace=False) \
  .T.stack().reset_index()

  type2     type1  col1  col2
0    me  clothing   500   600
1    me      food   300   200
2   you  clothing   200   700
3   you      food   600   500
4    us  clothing   300  -100
5    us      food  -300  -300
```

Comment: eval!  +1  I need to use this more.